# Is comparing the performance of a functional program to its equivalent non-functional program when both are written in the same language valid?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, performance-testing, programming-languages

I would like to see whether functional programming could be usable in implementing certain algorithms, so I am planning to write a functional version of that algorithm in Scala and compare it with the non-functional version in Scala.

I am wondering if I will actually get to capture the effect of FP when I test both programs, as I am worried that while the higher level code will look different, the lower level machine code after compilation will end up being (almost) the same. If this is the case, what languages would you recommend I use for writing both programs to capture the effect of FP as accurately as possible?

Comment: it depends on the algorithm which you want to implement, but in most cases you will see that difference in Scala. On JVM, you should also take into account the allocation rate, which in case of fp implementation will be higher, due to the immutability of data structures.

Comment: [Trust no one, bench everything](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh)

Comment: This question not clearly defined and answer might be to wide - bottom line: as @MarioGalic suggested - you need measure exact cases. Bottom line: complicated abstractions always hard to optimize by JVM, independently it's OOP or FP style.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by capturing the effects of FP? Also, why wouldn't the comparison be valid if both are in the same language, actually that is the most valid comparison since it is more feasible for a team to change style than language, so most people would be interested in seeing if switching to a functional style can have a real impact on performance when using the same language. - Finally, most of those benchmarks are actually meaningless since for most common applications your bottles necks will be related to networking than to CPU.